# JQuery accessing text deep below unique id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an app that pulls our data from our existing website. As we have no known API, I have decided to use ajax with whateverorigin.org to pull the full HTML from our site, and parse it with jQuery from there.

Unfortunately, much of the data I need lies far below any unique ID's. With `$(data.contents).find("#unique").text()` I am able to retrieve data of the type:

```html
<div id="unique">
   <div>
      Text I want
   </div>
</div>
```

However, as the nesting gets deeper, like:

```html
<span id="unique2">
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>
              Text I want
```

that snippet always returns "".

I have tried chaining the levels together with `.join`, but that doesn't work either.

Code in context [here](https://github.com/JacksonKearl/WMBR-Mobile/blob/master/www/js/controllers.js), around line 40-50. The site I'm trying to access is wmbr.org. The id that works is `#now_on_the_air`, one of the id's that doesn't is `#recent_plays`. The log is empty.

Comment: `#recent_plays` isn't nested like in your second example above. `#recent_plays` is being returned as an empty span, at least when I load it: `<span id=\"recent_plays\"></span>`. Which, of course explains why you're getting an empty string when calling `.text()` on it.

Comment: Looking at the actual source, on wmbr.org, recent plays should not be empty.

Comment: You're right. It looks like whateverorigin.org is mangling the source that it returns. Maybe because recent_plays is a span that contains a table, which is technically invalid HTML? Can you just request the page directly with your AJAX call, rather than going through whateverorigin?

Comment: Oh, actually, I think I see what the problem is. It looks like recent plays is populated via AJAX after the page is loaded. I'm guessing that whateverorigin doesn't execute the JS for that. The solution definitely seems to get rid of whateverorigin. Obviously you wouldn't be able to use $.getJSON anymore, but I think you could work with $.ajax.